# Чтение списка из txt файла и перенос их на html страницу?

Tags: php, javascript

Извиняюсь, за избитый вопрос.. Но все никак не могу разобраться.

Есть txt-файл со списком товаров, например, с таким содержимым:

```
url-картинки | Название | Описание
url-картинки | Название | Описание
url-картинки | Название | Описание
...динамическое количество строк...
```

ВОПРОС:

**- Как будет выглядеть скрипт чтения txt файла и вывод данных на html страницу, где каждая строка выводится отдельным новым div?**

Примерная схема блока для одного товара:

```
<div>
    <img src="URL">
    <p id="Name"></p>
    <p id="Desсription"></p>
</div>
```

p.s. не рассматриваю конвертацию в другой формат (csv или json). А также плагины, так как там у меня будет еще больше вопросов и проблем(

Всем спасибо за участие. Вы делаете мир лучше.

Comment: Какие Ваши попытки на этом тернистом пути? Почему не использовать более подходящие форматы хранения?

Comment: txt самый простой. excel - нужен будет плагин чтения, csv - нужно его оформлять.

Comment: А `JSON`?......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант:

```
$fh = fopen('filename.txt','r'); // Open file
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {    // Read line from file
  $tmp = explode("|", $line); // Get data from file
?>
 <!-------- html code -------->
<div>
    <img src="<?= $tmp[0] ?>"> <!-------- ImageURL -------->
    <p><?= $tmp[1] ?></p> <!-------- Name -------->
    <p><?= $tmp[2] ?></p> <!-------- Description -------->
</div>

  <!-------- html code ends -------->
<?php } // while closing 
fclose($fh); // closing file handler
?>
```

---

**UPD:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .item{
        display: inline-block
    }
</style>

<div class="main">
<?php

$fh = fopen('filename.txt','r');
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
  // <... Do your work with the line ...>
  // echo($line);
  $tmp = explode("|", $line);
?>
<div class="item">
    <img src="<?= $tmp[0] ?>"> <!-------- Image url -------->
    <p><?= $tmp[1] ?></p> <!-------- Name -------->
    <p><?= $tmp[2] ?></p> <!-------- Description -------->
</div>



<?php }
fclose($fh);
?>

</div>
```

Comment: Тех, кто мешает HTML и PHP, будут жарить одновременно в сковороде и котле.

Comment: @Other возможно, если котел в сковородке.

Comment: И всё это в паровой бане!

Comment: Код рабочий!  Подскажите, как все это публиковать в html в отдельных div блоках? сейчас все оформляется сплошь в один столбец

Comment: Как вариант поправить запись товара на:
<div class="item"> | url-картинки | Название | Описание | </div>

Comment: @Mesuti `display: inline-block` в классе `css`, а дальше прописываете свои стили.

Comment: Ваш код гениально компактный! спасибо! ошибку решил, это мои кривые руки